# How to show that disjoint closed sets have disjoint open supersets?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Theorem:
>   Let $S_0, S_1 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be disjoint and closed.
>   Then there exist disjoint open sets
>   $T_0, T_1 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
>   $S_0 \subset T_0, S_1 \subset T_1$.

How to prove this theorem without Urysohn functions? I know that $S_0^c$ contains $S_1$ and vise versa, but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Why don't you want to use Urysohn functions ?

Comment: @Nitrogen In my textbook this theorem comes before Urysohn functions, so I suppose that there is a way to prove it without Urysohn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For every $x \in S_0$, take an open ball $B(x,\epsilon_x)$ disjoint from $S_1$ and for every $y \in S_1$, take an open ball $B(y,\epsilon_y)$ disjoint from $S_0$. Let $$T_0=\bigcup_{x\in S_0}B(x,\frac{\epsilon_x}{2}) \ \ \ T_1=\bigcup_{y\in S_1}B(y,\frac{\epsilon_y}{2}).$$ Then $T_0$ and $T_1$ are open sets containing $S_0$ and $S_1$, and it's easy to see that they are disjoint.

PS: This argument works for every metric space.

Comment: Why do you have to divide the radii by $2$?

Comment: It is necessary if you want $T_0$ and $T_1$ to be disjoint (which follows from the triangle inequality).

Comment: I noticed that the disjoint sets need not be closed by your solution. am i right?

Comment: @SriKrishnaSahoo  No, that conclusion is not correct. Nitrogen used that the sets were closed to find the balls $B(x,\epsilon_x)$ and $B(y,\epsilon_y)$.

Comment: Dividing the radii by 2 is important here since it guarantees that $T_0$ and $T_1$ are disjoint. For a conradiction, assume that there exists $a\in T_0\cap T_1$. Then, $d(x,a)<\epsilon_x/2$ and $d(y,a)<\epsilon_y/2$ for some $x$ and $y$. Then, the triangular inequality implies that $d(x,y)<(\epsilon_x+\epsilon_y)/2\leq max(\epsilon_x,\epsilon_y)$. However, $d(x,y)\geq max (\epsilon_x,\epsilon_y)$ since $x$ is not included in $B(y,\epsilon_y)$ and $y$ is not included in $B(y,\epsilon_x)$.

Answer (score 3):

For $S\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ we define the distance from $x$ to $S$ as
$$\operatorname d(x,S)=\inf\{\operatorname d(x,y):y\in S\}.$$
It is easy to see that $x\mapsto\operatorname d(x,S)$ is a continuous function, and that $\operatorname d(x,S)\gt0$ if $x\notin\bar S.$

Given disjoint closed sets $S_0,S_1$ the sets
$$T_0=\{x:\operatorname d(x,S_0)\lt\operatorname d(x,S_1)\},$$
$$T_1=\{x:\operatorname d(x,S_1)\lt\operatorname d(x,S_0)\}$$
are disjoint open sets with $S_0\subseteq T_0$ and $S_1\subseteq T_1.$

In a few words: points nearer to $S_0$ than $S_1$ go into $T_0,$ points nearer to $S_1$ than $S_0$ go into $T_1.$